# Return from an if switch inside a for loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple game (for the raspberry pi Sense HAT) and this code block checks to see if a pixel is blocked so the player can't walk on it.

```
def whitelist(x,y):
    for e in range(len(blacklist)):
        item = blacklist[e]
        cur_x = item[0]
        cur_y = item[1]
        if x == cur_x and y == cur_y:
            return True
    return False
```

This code produces the opposite result of what I want (I can only walk inside the ground). Switching the `True` and `False` lines works fine, but can someone please explain why? Following this code with the coordinates `(0,5)` which are not on the blacklist does not seem to me like it should work correctly, but it does.

Comment: You called the function `whitelist` but the code loops over a *blacklist*, and returns `True` if the blacklist is matched. How are you using this function?

Answer (score 1):

First let's make it simpler:

```
def whitelist(x,y):
    for cur_x, cur_y in blacklist:
        if x == cur_x and y == cur_y:
            return True
    return False
```

and yet more simpler:

```
(x, y) in blacklist
```

It returns true if and only if (x, y) is in blacklist.

Comment: 100% correct on simplification at the bottom, though the naming on the functional version suggests it should be inverse (return `true` if the point is *not* in `blacklist`). Also worth pointing out the `point in blacklist` version is O(1) if `blacklist` is defined in a set rather than a list, as is adding/removing points from it.